# Unable to load images from local library in GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am unable to make my local images render in the development server of my gatsby website. I am using gatsby and tailwindcss. I am trying to combine a filterable photo gallery and a light box. My problem is that the file paths do not work unless I use the url through graphql. I think this also affecting my light box because if you click on an image it will not display it and also show image not found for the light box.

I have tried to configure the `gatsby-source-filesystem` file path to access my images folder in my src. I also matched the array source path to the `/src/images/mbaglass1.jpeg`. This rendered the alt tag.

I have tried to import the file path through the `allFile` in grapql. This is my first time using it. I was unable to render the images on the page in the manner I require.

I did import the url from graphql which is successfully rendering the images on the page, but I am unable to make it function with my light box.

I have created a functioning light box for a different website and I have been able to make this filter function in this website, but I could use some guidance towards successfully combining the two.

Here is the component:

```
import ImageLightbox from "react-image-lightbox"
import React from "react"





const images = [
  {
    id: 1,
    src: "/src/images/mbaglass1.jpeg",
    category: "Frameless Showers",
    alt: "shower",
  
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    src: "/static/ddb59dd079ddf9b6b0caebc1a9f05078/mbaglass3.jpeg",
    category: "Frameless Showers",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    src: "/static/bbb4f3909b9421b16d474e1fa01805c4/mbaglass2.jpeg",
    category: "Mirrors",
  },
]

const categories = [
  "All",
  "Frameless Showers",
  "Sliding Showers",
  "Mirrors",
  "Miscellaneous",
]

class GalleryDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      lightboxIsOpen: false,
      currentImage: 0,
      currentCategory: categories[0],
    }
    this.openLightbox = this.openLightbox.bind(this)
    this.closeLightbox = this.closeLightbox.bind(this)
    this.moveNext = this.moveNext.bind(this)
    this.movePrev = this.movePrev.bind(this)
    this.handleFilterChange = this.handleFilterChange.bind(this)
  }

  openLightbox(e, { index }) {
    this.setState({
      currentImage: index,
      lightboxIsOpen: true,
    })
  }

  closeLightbox() {
    this.setState({
      currentImage: 0,
      lightboxIsOpen: false,
    })
  }

  moveNext() {
    this.setState({
      currentImage: (this.state.currentImage + 1) % images.length,
    })
  }

  movePrev() {
    this.setState({
      currentImage:
        (this.state.currentImage - 1 + images.length) % images.length,
    })
  }

  handleFilterChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentCategory: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    <div>
    <ImageLightbox
      isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
      mainSrc={images[this.state.currentImage]}
      nextSrc={images[(this.state.currentImage + 1) % images.length]}
      prevSrc={
        images[(this.state.currentImage - 1 + images.length) % images.length]
      }
      onCloseRequest={this.closeLightbox}
      onMovePrevRequest={this.movePrev}
      onMoveNextRequest={this.moveNext}
    />
    </div>

    return (
        
      <>
<div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center py-4">
  {categories.map(category => (
    <button className="px-4 py-2 m-2 rounded-lg text-center text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600" onClick={() => this.handleFilterChange({target: {value: category}})}>{category}</button>
  ))}
</div>
<div className="grid p-8 lg:p-16 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-0 sm:gap-x-4 md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-x-8 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:gap-x-12" >
{images
.filter(
image =>
image.category === this.state.currentCategory ||
this.state.currentCategory === "All"
)
.map((image, index) => (
<a key={index} onClick={e => this.openLightbox(e, { index })}>
<img key={image.src} className="rounded-lg" src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />
</a>
))}
</div>
</>
)
}
}

export default GalleryDisplay;
```

Here is the gatsby-config file:

```
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-config/
 */

/**
 * @type {import('gatsby').GatsbyConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteMetadata: {
      title: `Gatsby`,
      siteUrl: `https://www.gatsbyjs.com`,
      description: `Blazing fast modern site generator for React`,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
// This will impact how browsers show your PWA/website
        // https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/
        // theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by first importing the image at the top of the component e.g. `import mbaglass2 from "../mbaglass2.jpeg"`, then using its import name `mbaglass2` in the array source. It seems it was a simple fix that way overlooked.